# Jquery Mobile and JSON

Tags: android, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need help to understand a weird environment of my web app.

I'm trying to create an app with Phonegap and jQuery mobile. I have a problem with the refresh of the *listview*. I download data from JSON and create a list of elements.

The list isn't correctly downloaded/styled, but if I refresh the browser I see it correctly.

What's the problem?

Next you can see the HTML and Javascript pages.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>CATEGORIA THRILLER</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="thrillerListPage" data-role="page" data-theme="a">

<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
<a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
<h1>THRILLER</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <ul id="thrillerList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="a"></ul>
    </div>       
</div>
<script src="js/libri-list.js"></script>
<script src="js/libri-details.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var serviceURL = "/services/";
var employees;

$(document).ready (function() {
getThrillerList();
});

$(document).delegate('#thrillerListPage','pageshow', function(event) {   
     getThrillerList();
});
$('#thrillerListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getThrillerList();
});

function getThrillerList() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'get-lista-libri-thriller.php', function(data) {
        $('#thrillerList li').remove();
        employees = data.items;

        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            $('#thrillerList').append('<li><a href="libri-details.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
                    '<img src="employee.img + '" width="58px" height="80px" />' +
                    '<h4>' + employee.title + '</h4>' +
                    '<p>' + employee.info1 + '</p>' +
                    '</a></li>');
        });
        $('#thrillerList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

Hope somebody can help me!

Thank you!

Comment: why are you loading `jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css` and `mobile-1.3.2.min.css`?

Comment: Here one error javascript in your #thrillerList.append(). See upadted code below

Answer (score 0):

```
function getThrillerList() {
  $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'get-lista-libri-thriller.php', function(data) {
    $('#thrillerList li').remove();
    employees = data.items;
    $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
        $('#thrillerList').append('<li><a href="libri-details.html?id=' + employee.id + '"><img src="'+employee.img + '" width="58px" height="80px" /><h4>' + employee.title + '</h4><p>' + employee.info1 + '</p></a></li>');

    });
    $('#thrillerList').trigger('create');
    $('#thrillerList').listview('refresh');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I've tried but it doesn't still work :( i have to refresh the page manually to shows datas